# The Ubuntu CD doesn't start

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows-8

Well I have a new HP Pavilion. It runs with Windows 8.1 and I hate it. I want to install Ubuntu Gnome but I can't because when I put in the CD the CD doesn't start.

Comment: Have you changed the Boot Order/BIOS to boot from the CD-Rom first before the Hard Drive...then reboot.

Comment: how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose to boot it from the <kbd>F9</kbd> window. If this doesn't show up when you start your laptop you have to set the `BIOS UEFI` to **disable** mode or **legacy** mode. Save the BIOS and restart the machine then you will be able to boot from it.

**UPDATE**

When you just power it on and press <kbd>F9</kbd>, you should see this

[image]

Scroll down with arrows to CD/DVD and hit enter!

Comment: So you mean the Start Up Menu?

Comment: I will update with pictures :)

Comment: If you can't do it can you take a photo when you just power it up?

Comment: you mean a screenshot? :/ I don't know how to make one..

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm horrible when I do things like this for the first time :S

Comment: Technically you can't take screenshot of first bluescreen you get like [this](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/157/c02120758.jpg) one. Did you try to press F9 directly and choose this. I wouldn't recommend doing any installation if you can't handle this. First try to read more or do it with a friend. You might run in many known problems for a dual boot system and you won't be able to use your computer before fixing configuration.

Comment: I reached the Boot menu. There I can choose between 'OS Boot Manager' and 'Boot Form EFI File'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the CD has the BOOT flag on.
As well, check if your primary boot device is setup to CD/DVD (in BIOS) and not to HDD.

Comment: thanks :) Well there is another problem.. I'm not very good at such things bc I have no Idea of BOOT lags, BIOS and HDD ect. .. do you know how I can make sure this? Thanks:)

Comment: Put the CD in. Restart. On HP Pavilion press F10 key to access BIOS. Check BOOT device. Select DVD/CD as primary. Exit. Second option (suggested by @OdinRW ) press F9 to select boot device after restart.

Comment: Well I reached the Boot Menu. I can choose between OS Boot Manager and Boot Form EFI file. What do I have Tod choose now?